# How can json data be shown in jquery $.each

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am using `$.each` loop for the json response i am getting here it is

```
["errors",[
        {"element":"country_name","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},
        {"element":"dial_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},    
        {"element":"country_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"}
    ]
]

$.each(response.errors, function (i, field) {
    alert(field);
});
```

But i dont get any alert. Can anyone tell how this can be achieved

**New Update**

actually i am using zend framework and converting an array named $messages which seems like this

```
Array
(
[country_name] => Array
(
[isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty
)

[dial_code] => Array
(
[isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty
)

[country_code] => Array
(
[isEmpty] => Value is required and can't be empty
)

)
```

then i am converting this array to what i actually need like this

```
<?php 
foreach ($messages as $key => $value) {

$errors[] = array("element"=>$key,"error"=>$value['isEmpty']);
}
?>
```

then i convert this to json encode and return to success function

```
<?php
$response = $this->getResponse();
$response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
$response->setContent(json_encode(array("errors",$errors)));
return $response;
?>
```

Comment: Check console for errors.

Comment: it says "TypeError: a is undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON response:

```
[
  "errors",
  [
    {"element":"country_name","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},
    {"element":"dial_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},    
    {"element":"country_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"}
  ]
]
```

is an array of two elements. The first element is string `"errors"`, and the second is array of objects. So, you should loop over the second element of the response (i.e. `response[1]`), like that:

```
$.each(response[1], function (i, field) {
    console.log(field);
});
```

Also, I recommend you using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging.

For running example see [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nu439quu/).

Comment: but in my browser it shows this error "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a"

Comment: hey i am also using "var response = JSON.stringify(data);" and when i alert this response then it shows me that json string that ia m using . Is there any concern with stringifying the data with this ?

Comment: @phpdevp if you stringify your data like `var response = JSON.stringify(data);` and then trying to do `$.each(response[1], ...)` ... yes it does matter as the `stringify` will convert your data to string. You should do `var response = data;` instead.

Comment: @phpdevp not sure what is the strategy that you're using when you accept answers, but you should consider timing and in this case my answer was first.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Maybe my answer gives better explanation.

Comment: Sorry @Gothdo but i can't see any _better explanation_ (hope that you're not talking about the note at the end). your answer has almost the same content of my answer second part.

Answer (score 3):

Your json should be like :

```
var response={"errors":[
   {"element":"country_name","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},
   {"element":"dial_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},    
   {"element":"country_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"}]
}
```

Since right now you have json that contain two columns first contain word `errors` and second contain 3 objects.

```js
var response={"errors":[
  {"element":"country_name","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},
  {"element":"dial_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},    
  {"element":"country_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"}]
};

$.each(response.errors, function (i, field) {
  console.log(field);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you don't  want to change your JSON structure you could target the second column `response[1]` instead :

```js
var response=["errors",[
  {"element":"country_name","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},
  {"element":"dial_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},    
  {"element":"country_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"}
]];

$.each(response[1], function (i, field) {
  console.log(field);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: His JSON is perfectly valid, there is no reason that his JSON should be different. Sometimes we can't change JSON sent by other party.

Comment: I'm not refering in my post that it's not a valid JSON, i'm just saying that with current JSON structure (he/she) can't get objects using `response.errors`, and if (he/she) can't change JSON structure just could use `response[1]`, check my update

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue with your json can you try the code below ?

```
$(function(){
  var response = {"errors":
  [{
    "element": "country_name",
    "error": "Value is required and can't be empty"
  },
  {
    "element": "dial_code",
    "error": "Value is required and can't be empty"
  },
  {
    "element": "country_code",
    "error": "Value is required and can't be empty"
  }]}

  $.each(response.errors, function (index, piece) {
    $.each(piece,function(key,value){
        alert(key+"--"+value);
    })
  });
});
```

And a working example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/hh3r7y36/

---

Here is update for your php code, your output should be something like that

```
<?PHP
    //Create new object
    $responseObject = new stdClass();
    //Create new object property as an array which means you are going to output "errors" as an json key not an array item
    $responseObject->errors = array();
    //Populate the response
    foreach ($messages as $key => $value) {
        $responseObject->errors[] = array("element"=>$key,"error"=>$value['isEmpty']);
    }

    //Create output
    $response->setContent(json_encode($responseObject));
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what if i use this [{"element":"country_name","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},{"element":"dial_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},{"element":"country_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"}]

Comment: @phpdevp That means you are creating an array without a parent key which means if you $.each(response) each iteration of your look like will be `{"element":"....","error":"..."}`

Comment: @phpdevp it will work you can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/uw35kygk/

Comment: i am using exactly what you have written but its showing this error "ypeError: invalid 'in' operand a"

Comment: The JSON in the question is valid, it is an array of two elements, one string and other array

Comment: @stjepano its wrong since he try to access `response.errors`

Comment: @phpdevp does the jsfiddle works on your browser ? I mean the example links.

Comment: @CihanUygun it can also be that the JSON is correct and his use of `response.errors` is incorrect

Comment: @stjepano yes, but "issue" does not mean "not valid", the issue means that the programming paradigm has issue in the code blocks relations.

Comment: @phpdevp so you should share how you are creating the json so we can help you in more proper way

Comment: @phpdevp you can checkout my update hope this helps, you should take the necessary parts to your code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106796/discussion-between-cihan-uygun-and-php-devp).

Comment: @CihanUygun its working now and thnxx for your help too i really appriciate thnx alot

Answer (score 0):

What you do here:

```
$response->setContent(json_encode(array("errors",$errors)));
```

will result in the JSON:

```
["errors",[
        {"element":"country_name","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},
        {"element":"dial_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},    
        {"element":"country_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"}
    ]
]
```

Which is valid but a bit unusual. To access your errors array you can do:

```
var response = data; // data is JSON from server
$.each(response[1], function (i, field) {
  console.log(field); // alert(field);
});
// response[0] is string "errors"
// response[1] is array of error message objects
```

If you want JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "errors":[
     {"element":"country_name","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},
     {"element":"dial_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"},    
     {"element":"country_code","error":"Value is required and can't be empty"}
  ]
}
```

you need to change your server code to:

```
$response->setContent(json_encode(array("errors" => $errors)));
```

then you can work with your response data like this:

```
var response = data; // data is JSON from server
$.each(response.errors, function (i, field) {
  console.log(field); // alert(field);
});
```

Comment: your answer is right too but a bit late but thnxx for the help its working now